# Unable to Add Filtered Index but don't Understand Why

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-project, filtered-index

I am trying to update a database from a database project in Visual Studio.

The update script is generated automatically. On line 133, the script adds a filtered index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ProgramCodes_Value]
    ON [dbo].[ProgramCodes]([Value] ASC) WHERE ([IsDeleted]=(0));
```

But this line produces some errors:

> (133,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1935, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot create index. Object 'ProgramCodes' was created with the following SET options off: 'ANSI_NULLS'.
>
> (133,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
>   CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ProgramCodes_Value]
>       ON [dbo].[ProgramCodes]([Value] ASC) WHERE ([IsDeleted] = (0));
>
> An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

First off, I really don't understand the ANSI_NULLS thing. Usually, this is just a harmless warning.

Second, I can see it failed when trying to add the filtered index, but I really can't see why. Checking the data, there are no duplicates that would violate this unique index.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to understanding the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> `SET ANSI_NULLS` must also be `ON` when you are creating or changing indexes on computed columns or indexed views. If `SET ANSI_NULLS` is `OFF`, any `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` statements on tables with indexes on computed columns or indexed views will fail. SQL Server will return an error that lists all `SET` options that violate the required values. Also, when you execute a `SELECT` statement, if `SET ANSI_NULLS` is `OFF`, SQL Server will ignore the index values on computed columns or views and resolve the select operation as if there were no such indexes on the tables or views.

Comment: I'll need some time to try and absorb this. So, am I getting one error or two? Is the failure to create the index just because of the ANSI_NULLS thing?

Comment: @JonathanWood yes, it's pretty much obvious from the error message. Also `ProgramCodes` seems to be an indexed view upon which you can't create filtered indexes anyway.

Comment: It might be obvious to someone more intimately familiar with SQL Server. At any rate, `ProgramCodes` is just a table.